# faster, very accurate approximation for tanh

Tags: approximation, hyperbolic-function

I was playing with tanh and what would be very close but not as expensive as tanh, computation wise. I came up with:

```
      2/(1+exp(-2*x))-1
```

It is VERY close. The biggest delta I saw was like in the 10 to the -15 range. It's still not as cheap as polynomial approximations.

Can somebody differentiate that for me?
:)

Comment: [Use wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2F%281%2Bexp%28-2*x%29%29-1)

Comment: What a nifty site! Thanks a lot.

Comment: OOOPsss!!! I think this IS the tanh formula rewritten. replace the 1 with (1+exp(2*x))/(1+exp(2*x)). You end up with (1-exp(2*x))/(1+exp(2x)). I started with the sigmoid formula and modified it to make it look like tanh. The sigmoid, 1/(1+exp(x)), looks a lot like tanh but its range is [0,1]. So I multiplied the sigmoid by 2 and subtracted 1 making the range [-1,1]. but the modified sigmoid had a much lower slope near 0 so I replaced the exp(x) with exp(2x) and voila! It matched tanh so close... Now I know why!

Answer (score 2):

1-(2*(1/(1+exp(x*2)))) works well on limited hardware